# Simultaneous Column Filtering using ShieldUI

Tags: jquery, html, css, shieldui

I am fairly new to web development and I've come across ShieldUI's grid widget. Their demo version offers a lot of easily customizable codes but I cannot get to do simultaneous column filtering. I created the select options in the toolbar (bottom) but these select filters are independent of each other. What I want is simultaneous column filtering using the select filters at the bottom of the table.

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yabi/x8h829ue/5/) here. Here's a sample [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSslT.png) of what I'm doing.

Here's what I have done so far: js file, css file, html file.

Note that there are loaded js to make this work, please see fiddle.

Thank you all.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
   
   //------------------------Basic Initialization------------------------------------
   $("#grid").shieldGrid({
    dataSource: {
     data: gridData                 
    },
    sorting: {
     multiple: true
    },
    rowHover: true,
    scrolling: true,
    resizing: true,
    columnReorder: true,
    height: "450px",
    filtering: {
     enabled: false
    },
    paging: {
     pageSize: 12
    },
    events: {
     detailCreated: detailCreated,
     command: command
    },
    columns: [                
     { field: "id", width: "70px", title: "ID" },
     { field: "name", title: "Person Name" },
     { field: "age", title: "Age" },
     { field: "company", width: "170px", title: "Company Name"},
     { field: "balance", title: "Balance" }
    ],
    toolbar: [
     {
     template: $("#template").html(),
     position: "bottom"
     }
    ],    
   });
   
   $("#Age").shieldDropDown({
            events:
                {
                    select: function (e) {
                        var dataSource = $("#grid").swidget().dataSource,
                            value = e.item.value;
                        if (value) {
                            dataSource.filter = { path: "age", filter: "eq", value: value };
                        }
                        else {
                            dataSource.filter = null;
                        }
                        dataSource.read();
                    }
                }
   });
   
   $("#Name").shieldDropDown({
            events:
                {
                    select: function (e) {
                        var dataSource = $("#grid").swidget().dataSource,
                            value = e.item.value;
                        if (value) {
                            dataSource.filter = { path: "name", filter: "eq", value: value };
                        }
                        else {
                            dataSource.filter = null;
                        }
                        dataSource.read();
                    }
                }
   });
   
   $("#Company").shieldDropDown({
            events:
                {
                    select: function (e) {
                        var dataSource = $("#grid").swidget().dataSource,
                            value = e.item.value;
                        if (value) {
                            dataSource.filter = { path: "company", filter: "eq", value: value };
                        }
                        else {
                            dataSource.filter = null;
                        }
                        dataSource.read();
                    }
                }
   });
  
   //--------------------------------Conditional Hierarchy-------------------------------
   function command(e) {
    // do not show the friends detail grid for female persons
    if (e.commandName == "expandButtonCreate") {
     if (e.item.gender == "female") {
      e.cancel = true;
     }
    }
   }
   function detailCreated(e) {
    // add a nested grid to the row, containing the person's friends
    $("<div/>")
     .appendTo(e.detailCell)
     .shieldGrid({
      dataSource: {
       data: e.item.friends
      },
      sorting: {
       multiple: true
      },
      paging: {
       pageSize: 5
      },
      columns: [
       { field: "id", width: "100px", title: "Friend ID" },
       { field: "name", title: "Friend Name" }
      ]
     });
   }
   

   
   //-------------------------Search Box 1---------------------------------------------
   var TableSource = $("#grid").swidget().dataSource,
                input = $("#filterbox input"),
                timeout,
                value;
            input.on("keydown", function () {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    value = input.val();
                    if (value) {
                        TableSource.filter = {
                            or: [
                                { path: "id", filter: "contains", value: value },
                                { path: "name", filter: "contains", value: value },
                                { path: "company", filter: "contains", value: value },
                                { path: "phone", filter: "contains", value: value },
                                { path: "age", filter: "contains", value: value }
                            ]
                        };
                    }
                    else {
                        TableSource.filter = null;
                    }
                    TableSource.read();
                }, 300);
            });
    
   //---------------------Show/Hide Columns------------------
   $("#columnChooser").shieldDropDown();
   $("#hideColumn").shieldButton({
    events: {
     click: function (e) {
      var columnName = $("#columnChooser").swidget().value();
      $("#grid").swidget().hideColumn(columnName);
     }
    }
   });
   $("#showColumn").shieldButton({
    events: {
     click: function (e) {
      var columnName = $("#columnChooser").swidget().value();
      $("#grid").swidget().showColumn(columnName);
     }
    }
   });
   
        });
```

```css
/*filterbox*/
        #filterbox {
            text-align: right;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
   font-family:Calibri;
   font-size: 2em;
        }
        #filterbox input {
            border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 260px;
        }
        #filterbox a {
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;
            width: 26px;
            height: 26px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #filterbox img {
            line-height: 0;
        }

/*Hide/Show Columns*/
    div .grid-config .sui-radiobutton
    {
        line-height: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .grid-config .sui-dropdown
    {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

/*Grid Div size*/
#grid {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
}

/*Toolbar*/
    .toolbar {
        float: left;
        padding-right: 10px;
  font-size:1em;
  font-family:Calibri;
    }
    .sui-grid .sui-toolbar {
        height: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-shield-template" id="template">
 <div class="toolbar">
  <label class="ageLabel" for="age">Filter by Age:</label>
  <select id="Age" style="width: 150px">
   <option value="">Choose value</option>
   <option value="32">32</option>
   <option value="33">33</option>
   <option value="35">35</option>
   <option value="36">36</option>   
   <option value="39">39</option>
   <option value="40">40</option>
  </select>
  <label class="nameLabel" for="name">Filter by Name:</label>
  <select id="Name" style="width: 150px">
   <option value="">Choose value</option>
   <option value="Sue Sharpe">Sue Sharpe</option>
   <option value="Juanita Weaver">Juanita Weaver</option>
  </select>
  <label class="companyLabel" for="company">Filter by Company:</label>
  <select id="Company" style="width: 150px">
   <option value="">Choose value</option>
   <option value="Applidec">Applidec</option>
   <option value="Syntac">Syntac</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 </script>
  
  <div id="filterbox">
   Search here:
   <input type="text" />
 </div>
  
 <div id="grid"></div>
 
 <div>
        Column: 
        <select id="columnChooser">
            <option value="id">ID</option>
            <option value="name">Person Name</option>
            <option value="company">Company Name</option>
            <option value="balance">Balance</option>
            <option value="age">Age</option>
        </select>
        <button id="hideColumn">Hide Column</button>
        <button id="showColumn">Show Column</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do filtering based on two conditions, you should set the `dataSource.filter` to an array or dictionary of filters.

Check [this documentation page](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/datasource/javascript/api/settings/filter) for more details.